# How to compare user input with array and execute command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to write a script to login into different systems by providing system name as input and making it variable by read option. However when i try to compare it with defined Array it's throwing me error and stating command not found.

Succeeded in making use input as variable but not able to compare it properly with defined array.
Below is the code i have written.

```
#!/bin/bash
cluster=("namico1c.mylabserver.com","namico2c.mylabserver.com")
echo "Please enter a Cluster Name to login: "
read clname
for item in ${cluster[@]};do
    echo ${item};
    if ["${clname}"="${item}"]; then
     ssh test@$clname
    else
     echo "Cluster is not correct"
    fi
done
```

```
[test@namico3c ~]$ ./test.sh
Please enter a Cluster Name to login: 
namico1c.mylabserver.com
namico1c.mylabserver.com,namico2c.mylabserver.com
./test.sh: line 7: [namico1c.mylabserver.com=namico1c.mylabserver.com,namico2c.mylabserver.com]: command not found
Cluster is not correct
```

Comment: Please paste your script [there](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to fix the syntax errors.

Comment: Add some spaces, as in `if [ "${clname}" = "${item}" ] ; then`

Comment: Remove `,` from declaration of array `cluster`.

Comment: After Couple of changes, its working fine now. Tq @LjmDullaart and Cyrus

Answer (score 1):

alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash
cluster=("namico1c.mylabserver.com" "namico2c.mylabserver.com")
select clname in "${cluster[@]}"; do
    ssh test@$clname
    break
done
```